# Работа с ветками в git

Tags: git, git-branch

Описание ситуации: есть 3 ветки master-> working_branch-> footer.

Состояние ветки footer:

**$ git status**

```
В ветке footer

Changes not staged for commit:
  (используйте "git add <file>..." чтобы обновить данные для закрепления)
  (используйте "git checkout -- <file>..." чтобы отменить изменения в рабочей директории)

    modified:   templates/-----/index.php
```

**$ git checkout working_branch**

```
M   templates/gorobar/index.php  **////////Что это значит?**
```

Перешел к ветке 'working_branch'

**$ git status**

```
В ветке working_branch

Changes not staged for commit:
  (используйте "git add <file>..." чтобы обновить данные для закрепления)
  (используйте "git checkout -- <file>..." чтобы отменить изменения в рабочей директории)

    modified:   templates/-----/index.php
```

Не закомиченные изменения из ветки footer почему-то отображаются в ветке working_branch!!!
Почему?

Comment: @marina halembakova, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 5):

Все абсолютно правильно. Стандартное поведение для большинства систем контроля версий. Когда Вы переключаете ветку, а у Вас есть незакоммиченные данные (что уже само по себе идеологически неверно), то git (svn, cvs) делают merge изменений. Собственно это Вы и наблюдаете.

Поэтому, либо всегда коммите перед переключением, либо пользуйтесь "карманом" - `git stash`.

Answer (score 1):

Если бы вы сделали `git add` (добавили вы, то вам предложили бы закоммитить изменения в той ветке, в которой вы находились при переключении, и предупредили, что в противном случае изменения будут утеряны. Раз изменение не `staged` (как у вас), то git предполагает, что возможно вы хотите его закоммитить в другой ветке. Комитьте в той ветке, где нужно перед переключением, `git stash` легко забыть, а `git log` всегда под рукой. Добавить позже новые изменения в последний коммит можно `git stash --amend`'ом, а отменить коммит, но оставить изменения `git reset HEAD~1`. Можно и объединять комиты (в том случае, если ещё не пушили их в репозиторий, откуда их кто-то мог забрать).
И прочтите же уж [книгу](http://www.git-scm.com/book/ru), она бесплатная и на русском.